# Mongodb Phalcon how to search by ObjectId?

Tags: mongodb, phalcon

I need help with my rhyme;
Working in Robo3T
db.getCollection('aa').find({aa_id: ObjectId('5f10f1c013d7c9e017000033'),loai: 'mamnon'})

In phalcon not working

```
$docs= \aa::find([
        [
            'aa_id' =>  new ObjectId('5f10f1c013d7c9e017000033'),
            'loai' => 'mamnon'
        ]
    ]);
```

thanks so much all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just remove `new` and try?

```
$docs= \aa::find([
        [
            'aa_id' => ObjectId('5f10f1c013d7c9e017000033'),
            'loai' => 'mamnon'
        ]
    ]);
```